# How to download the file from webapi in Internet Explorer using angular post?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs http post to download the file from the Web Api on the button click.My code works fine in Google Chrome and Firefox but it is not working in the Internet Explorer. Here's my code

```
$scope.CallApi = function () {
        $http({
            url: some url,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            data: null,
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',    

        }).success(function (responsedata, status, xhr) {           
            var file = xhr('Content-Disposition');
            console.log(file); 
            var filename = file.substr(21, 7);
            $scope.value = responsedata;
            var fileName = filename;
            var blob = new Blob([responsedata], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            a.href = url;
           a.download = fileName;        

        }).error(function (error) {
                alert("Error Found" + " : " + error);
            });
    };
```

---

The above code is not working in IE,  I don't want to use FileSaver.js extension is there any other way to download the file from api in Internet Explorer.  Below I have attached the Screen Shot of the error that I am getting in the Internet Explorer....
[image]
Thank You in Advance.....

Comment: Sorry I have inserted image in between....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to download in IE

```
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
      // base64 string
      var base64str = response;
      // decode base64 string, remove space for IE compatibility
      var newstr =base64str.replace(/\s/g, '');
      var binary = atob(newstr);
      // get binary length
      var len = binary.length;
      // create ArrayBuffer with binary length
      var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
      // create 8-bit Array
      var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);

      // save unicode of binary data into 8-bit Array
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      // create the blob object with content-type "application/csv"               
      var blob = new Blob( [view], { type: mimeType });
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "Name your file here");
}
```

here mimeType would be application/octet-stream for you and response is your base64 string.

Comment: Thank you Rakeschand for your valuable comments but it uses third party tool to download is any other way which not uses the third party tool like previously i have done using the filesaver.js but filesaver.js is a third party tool i don't need like this

Comment: window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob is giving undefined

Comment: No it's not FileSaver.js and did you try in IE because in IE it will not be undefined.

Comment: But for other browser it will not support 'msSaveOrOpenBlob'

Comment: you said your code is working in other browsers. you can put that code in else part.